# MLE of Weibull in the context of Survival analysis

Tags: survival, weibull-distribution

I have the following likelihood (Weibull model with parameter $\alpha, \lambda$), and I would like to maximize it with respect to $\alpha, \lambda$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
L (\alpha, \lambda; t, \delta) &= \prod_{i=1}^n \left[\left(\alpha \lambda x_i^{\alpha - 1}\right)^{\delta_i} \exp(-\lambda x_i^\alpha) \right] \\
&= (\alpha\lambda)^{\sum \delta_i}  \left( \prod x_i^{\delta_i(\alpha - 1)} \right) \exp( - \lambda \sum x_i^\alpha)
\end{aligned}
$$

It is known that the solution should be approached via numerical method.

Is there anyone to suggest one (e.g. EM algorithm) that I can try?

Comment: Newton–Raphson method on log-likelihood. If not work, try EM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of points:

- Because of numerical stability, it is better to maximize the log-likelihood instead of the likelihood.
- For the specific case of the Weibull model for censored data (what I gather based on the notation you have), Newton-type algorithms are most often used.
- You could try Newton-Raphson, but it is most often sufficient to work with a quasi-Newton algorithm, such as the BFGS, that numerically approximates the Hessian matrix.
- Crude application of the Newton-Raphson it is not always guaranteed to work, and often step-halving and/or positive-definite modifications to the Hessian are required. Therefore, it is advisable to work with routines that have these adjustments already implemented. If you have to work in R, you can have a look at the `optim()` function.